# IE 11 not displaying font weights correctly from Google Fonts

Tags: css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, fonts, google-font-api

IE 11 is not displaying my specified font weights correctly from Google Fonts.  I can not get the problem to replicate in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9zxu53yj/)

When using Google Fonts the font weight is displayed correctly if I only specify one weight i.e.  if I import the fonts with the following link the light version is brought in.

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:300" rel="stylesheet">
```

If change the link like so:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400" rel="stylesheet">
```

The regular weight is brought in.

However if I try to import both weights IE 11 only shows the heavier font despite me specifying font weight in the CSS.  Chrome shows the light version as it should.

Link:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:300,400" rel="stylesheet">
```

CSS:

```
.light {
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.regular {
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<p class="light">This Is A Test Of Google Fonts Displayed in IE 11</p>
<p class="regular">This Is A Test Of Google Fonts Displayed in IE 11</p>
```

Chrome Screenshot:

[image: Chrome Screenshot]

IE Screenshot:

[image: IE Screenshot]

---

Full Local HTML for Test case:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Font Test Page</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:300,400" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
.light {
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.regular {
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 16px;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<p class="light">This Is A Test Of Google Fonts Displayed in IE 11
</p>
<p class="regular">This Is A Test Of Google Fonts Displayed in IE 11
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works as it should on my comp. Here is the screenshot of the IE11 version. http://screencast.com/t/7dImeYayn9

Comment: @Valius79  Thanks for the screenshot.  I have updated my question with a similar type screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

According to *Can I Use...* Internet explorer 6-11 doesn't support the `font-weight:<number>` syntax: 
[image] (source: https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_properties_font-weight_number )

A solution for that browser would be to have differently named font definitions for all the needed weights.